# Making text fields autocomplete in views exposed filters

Tags: 7, views, forms

I want to make a text field auto complete in a views exposed form. I tried using the following code but nothing happens(I don't see that blue icon in the text field):

```
<?php
function nk_menu() {
    $items['nk/autocomplete'] = array(
        'page callback' => '_nk_autocomplete',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}
function nk_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') &&  ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-page')) {
        $form['title']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'nk/autocomplete';
        $form['title']['#default_value'] = 'abcd'; // this one also doesn't work
        print_r($form); // to be sure that properties has been added to the form (they are added)
    }
}

function _nk_autocomplete($string) {
  // ...
}
```

Why doesn't it work? I know that there is a module for that, but I want to know why mine doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Views change elements after form generation, so you should add own after build function:

```
function nk_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') &&  ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-page')) {
      $form['#after_build'][] = 'nk_views_mypage_exposed_after_build';
    }
}

function nk_views_mypage_exposed_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['title']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'nk/autocomplete';
  $form['title']['#default_value'] = 'abcd'; // this one also doesn't work
//  print_r($form); // I recommend to use dsm function of devel module, instead of print_r.
  return $form;
}
```